# VPP account - will the user see a badge on the app store if an update is available?

Tags: ios, apple-vpp

If we distribute an app through an VPP account (Volume Purchase), will the user also get a badge on the AppStore Dashboard icon, if an update is available (like with the 'normal' user accounts?)

Comment: do you get answer to you question? we updated a custom b2b app but our client iPads doesn't receive any notification for the new version.

Comment: Some colleagues told me that the it should work. But I can't confirm it, since I havn't seen it myself...

Comment: Thanks you for feedback, I ve just get confirmation that iPad still have old version and not get notified for the newest available version in custom b2b (available more then 60 days ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [comparison table of the VPP features](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202995) for the three possible distribution paths "MDM User Assignment", "MDM Device Assignment" and "Redemption codes".

The way I understand the table is that automatic updates through the App Store are available if you distribute via redemption codes OR assign the app via MDM directly to the user / Apple ID.

Only if you assign it via MDM directly to a device (no Apple ID required), it will not have a connection to the store and therefore not provide any automatic updates. However, if you have the MDM in place, you push updates through that anyway.

Comment: I am distributing an app via VPP redemption codes and thus far it is absolutely NOT updating or badging-for-update any of the half-dozen users who have the app. It's been 24 hours since the app update became available.

Comment: @RealHandy very interesting to get first hand experience. Did the apps eventually get an update? If not it might be a good reason to get in touch with Apple developer support for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! After about a day — I’m not sure whether it was closer to 24 or 36 hours — every user either got auto-updated or got the badge. It just took a lot longer than you’d think. Thanks for asking — I got the email letting me know to respond or I wouldn’t have remembered to.